# Can no longer fold python dictionaries in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used to be able to collapse (fold) python dictionaries just fine in my VS Code.  Randomly I am not able to do that anymore.  I can still fold classes and functions just fine, but dictionaries cannot fold, the arrow on the left hand side just isn't there.  I've checked my settings but I can't figure out what would've changed.  I'm not sure the best forum to go to for help, so I'm hoping this is ok.  Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on plug-ins in your VSCode. Perhaps you disable plug-ins one by one to test. If this cannot work, uninstall and install VSCode, then add plug-ins back one by one and test.

Comment: @yoonghm
Thank you so much!  So weird, it was Pylance by Microsoft that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's caused by Pylance v2022.1.1. Use v2022.1.0 instead.

Issue [#2248](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2248)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you!

Comment: for those struggling as of 10/26/22, it seems like v2022.10.30 (released 6 days ago) also causes this problem and I had to revert back to 10.20 which then worked. created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3543) for it as well

Comment: as other answers show, it can also be caused by the Jupyter extension.

Answer (score 14):

For me, it wasn't a problem with Pylance but rather with Jupyter[*] extensions.

I disabled all my extensions and enabled them one by one. See that enabling the Python extension will not just enable Python extension. I disabled Jupyter related extensions and Pylance wasn't the problem.

Comment: I disabled Jupyter extension and everything is back!

Comment: FYI, here is the issue found in Jupyter extension repo. (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11703)

Answer (score 3):

I can also confirm that the Jupyter notebook VSCode extensions was the culprit for me. It doesn't disable just the dictionary folding. It straight up disables any code folding abilities in the .py files.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of yoonghm's comment, I found out it was the Pylance by Microsoft extension causing the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is  the latest Pylance version 2022.1.1 caused it, the issue has been raised in the [github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2248)

You could install the older version:

1. Go to **Extensions**,
2. Find Pylance and click on the setting to **Install Another Version**.